# Alcubierre drive: what is the nature of exotic matter?

Tags: particle-physics, faster-than-light, warp-drives, exotic-matter

In connection with [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) we often hear about necessity of an exotic matter in order to produce a negative energy density. I suspect that such matter has no place in standard particle model.

**My question is what is [exotic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter)? Is it predicted by some particle model?**

Comment: You are right, it has no place in physics.

Comment: It's just matter with a negative energy density, that is, negative mass. (There's no good reason to suspect that such matter exists in our universe, and various reasons to think it's impossible).

Comment: TLDR: "Exotic matter" is not the name of some specific stuff that would meet the needs of Alcubierre. Rather, if there _was_ some kind of matter that met the needs of Alcubierre, then that matter would be "exotic," (i.e., something out of the ordinary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My question is what is a exotic matter? Is it predicted by another particle model (e.g. supersymetry theory)?*

It is difficult to find a uniform definition for the term "exotic matter", but an useful classification in the contest of general relativity is given by employing the so called *energy conditions*. They are inequalities that the Energy momentum tensor appearing in the right hand side of the Einstein field equations can satisfy or not.

The general classifications include the Null, weak, dominant and strong energy condition.
You can easily found a detailed explanation of the terms in standard textbook, I suggest General Relativity by Wald, which is extremely technical but also very precise on the topic.

Normally the energy conditions are used in order to study general properties of the Einstein field equations, and play an important role in the proof of the Singularity theorems of Penrose, Hawking et al.

On the other hand the necessity of "exotic" matter is crucial in cosmology to explain the accelerated expansion of the universe, which is an empirical evidence. 
Pragmatically speaking, the so called Dark Energy has negative pressure that cause the accelerated expansion, and apparently impossible to achieve in the contest of standard model of particle physics in a coherent way (it is possible to predict a vacuum energy in the contest of the standard model of particle physics but its value is too big to be compatible with cosmological data, this is the so called cosmological constant problem).

Something very similar to Dark Energy is also required to explain inflation, even if this is still more a paradigm which lacks definitive experimental evidence.

Must be stressed however that this kind of DE is very different from the "exotic matter" required for the Alcubierre solutions of the Einstein Field equations. However, if your question is not related with the Alcubierre metric, there are many extension of the Standard Model  that are invoked in order to explain the fundamental origin of Dak Energy, like string theory

Comment: It can hardly be over-emphasized how different is the concept of negative mass from the concept of positive mass with lots of tension. The first is straightforwardly contrary to physics; the second is merely surprising. By lumping both together under the name "exotic" I think this answer gives the very unhelpful and misleading impression that Alcubierre's unphysical model is somehow comparable to or equally meriting serious consideration as the observations in cosmology which imply accelerating expansion.

Comment: I am sorry if this is the impression my answer gives. I do not believe they are at all comparable, neither they have the same importance in physics. However the question was "what is exotic matter", and I believe that DE ( beyond the possible interpretation as vacuum energy) is undoubtedly one of the most important examples of such a thing in modern physics.

Comment: ok; sorry if my words were too strongly chosen.